# How to avoid scientific notation when converting small double values to string?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, string-conversion

I need to calculate the difference between the value of two Labels and I'm doing it correctly with the following code:

```
Label26.Text = (((CDbl(PREZZO) - CDbl(Label17.Text))
```

`(PREZZO)` is a string.

The problem comes when the difference is very small, like in my case `0.00008`, so I'm getting `8e-5` as result.
How can I get the normal number without the scientific notation?

Edit:
Formatting it with `"F5"` seems to work but I still got scientific notation sometimes like the following:

[image]
[image]

The string `PREZZO` corresponds to the value of `Price €`
`Label17.Text` to the value of `1H AGO €`.

Code:

```
 (CDbl(PREZZO) - CDbl(Label16.Text)).tostring("F5")
```

Comment: If `x = 0.00008` then `Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("P3"))` outputs 0.008% - is that what you're after?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I forgot to delete part of code I didn't need for this question. It's not my interest now to calculate the percentage, just the difference between the two labels.

Comment: Oh, ok, then maybe you want the ["F" format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#fixed-point-format-specifier-f): `Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("F5"))` for `x = 0.00008` outputs "0.00008".

Comment: Hmm I've tried and it seemed to work, but now I'll post a screenshot where for some numbers is still using the scientific notation...

Comment: Can you add the line of code which is still showing scientific notation? (Also, for currency, it is better to use the Decimal type instead of Double.)

Comment: I added the line of code. Does really matter in this case? the € symbol is contained in a simple label, so this is supposed to be just an arithmetical operation. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a numeric source for that data and you actually need to parse the content of UI elements, the Culture used when inserting data matters, because not all cultures use a comma as decimal separator: if the current UI Culture ([Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentculture) and [Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture)) don't match the input format (you show input that uses a comma instead of a dot - as the [InvariantCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) - to separate the decimal part), then the text will not parse correctly or at all.

If you have a text input that uses a specific culture format, you need to parse that input specifying the corresponding [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo).
Numbers don't have a format: if you have a numeric source, use that for the calculations, then present the data using the destination UI Culture to provide a localized representation of those value.

If the input Culture and the current Culture are the same, then you don't need to specify a CultureInfo when parsing string values, since the Culture returned by `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` is used.

---

Assuming that the input format is based on the Italian format for decimal numbers (assumption based on the use of the name `PREZZO`, which Google Translate detects as Italian), you can create a CultureInfo that provides standard formats used in that culture.

When parsing the string values, pass this CultureInfo to the methods, so the text will be parsed correctly.

Also, since you dealing with currency, don't use Double or `CDbl` to parse those values, use [Decimal.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse) instead. For example:

```
Dim PREZZO = "0,04831"
Dim currentPrice = Label16.Text ' "0,04840"

Dim culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("it-IT")

Dim price = Decimal.Parse(PREZZO, culture)
Dim price1Year = Decimal.Parse(currentPrice, culture)
Dim priceDiff = price1Year - price
Dim priceDiffPercent = priceDiff / price
```

Now, to present the calculated variation in price and the percentage of the variation, you need to format back those values using the same CultureInfo:

```
labelDiffPrice.Text = priceDiff.ToString("N5", culture)
labelDiffCurrency.Text = priceDiff.ToString("C5", culture)
labelDiffPercent.Text = priceDiffPercent.ToString("P5", culture)
```

`N5` specifies a number with a precision of 5 decimal values.
`C5` species to use Currency format and Symbol defined by the CultureInfo, with a precision of 5 decimal values. This overrides the [CultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimaldigits), so it should be used for a specific  purpose, as in this case.
`P5` a percentage representation of a number multiplied by `100` with a precision of 5 decimal positions.

The two calculated values will be presented as:

```
 ' Variation in price
 0,00009

 ' Variation in price expressed in currency
 € 0,00009

 ' Percentage of the variation
 0,18630%
```

If the input comes directly from a User, use [Decimal.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse) instead of `Decimal.Parse()` to validate the input.

See also: [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Answer (score 0):

you can use .ToString("F"&c) instead of "F5", because you dont know how many decimals are in difference input. so we can calculate no of digits in both the input and find the great and pass it to ToString("F" & c) here c is greater number of digits of 2 inputs. it will not always greater than that.

```
Dim a = Len(Label1.Text)
Dim b = Len(Label2.Text)
Dim c

If a > b Then
  c = a
Else
  c = b
End If

TextBox1.Text = (CDbl(Label1.Text) - CDbl(Label2.Text)).ToString("F" & c)
```